# Attempting to Implement a Thread for a Game Loop

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am a novice learning Android development and the next step I must take is to be capable to understanding threads to be able to implement a game loop.

I have taken knowledge from google and StackOverflow and snippets from examples to come up with a lump of code that seems to not be working:

- [MainActivity.java](http://pastie.org/8870638)
- [GameSetup.java](http://pastie.org/8870692)
- [GameView.java](http://pastie.org/8870712)
- [activity_main.xml](http://pastie.org/8870756)
- [game_setup.xml](http://pastie.org/8870758)

MainActivity.java is a simply title screen with a play button. This seems to work fine and will link to the next activity. However, I am getting a crash whenever I attempt to load up the next activity. My guestimations based on the error lead me to believe that threads have issues with RelativeActivity, but I'm not so sure on what the issue may be exactly, I am rather confused.

[Here](http://pastie.org/8870789) is the error I am getting thrown, I am having issues trying to decipher the issue with it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`R.id.layout` is a `RelativeLayout` but you are trying to cast it to `GameView`, that's causing your crash.

Edit:

To  add your `GameView` to the `RelativeLayout` you can do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <com.your.package.GameView
    android:id="@+id/my_game_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ship1" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ship1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and retrive it with

```
 GameView myGameView = (GameView) findViewById(R.id.my_game_view);
```

Comment: So how exactly should I be declaring my layouts for use within GameView? I'm not sure exactly what the issue is and how else to declare a layout with relative positioning

Comment: you can declare your `GameView` inside the `RelativeLayout` and give it the position that you like.

Comment: Thanks for the edit there. I will do what I can with this. However I am not entirely sure where I should be calling GameView. I have setup [This](http://pastie.org/8872137) snippet of code to call the gameview within my GameSetup.java file, but I am not entirely sure what I have done is correct. How exactly should I call this? [This](http://pastie.org/8872186) is the error I am getting with this.

(I would vote you up but I am at 14/15 reputation)

Comment: I am thinking that perhaps I should be linking it within my GameView rather than the setup? Or maybe not? I'm not entirely sure. [Here](http://pastie.org/8872235) is the full code for reference.

Comment: you are developing your application.. you know what the purpose of those classes :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, from the code you have written so far, I can explain the reason for the ClassCastException.

- You are declaring a RelativeLayout in both XML files.
- Both RelativeLayouts use the same android:id "@+id/layout"
- In GameView.java you try to find a view by specifying the id
      m_game = (GameView) findViewById(R.id.layout);
- IMO you are retrieving one of the RelativeLayouts and then try to cast it to a GameView. As this is not possible, Java throws the exception.